# UICollectionViewCell. I want to add 2 different picture cells

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "MyCell"

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var myimage = UIImage(named: "1433584709_clock_ios7_ios_7")  

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!  

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.image = myimage
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = CollectionViewLayout()
        self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

I have this code to add so many cells with same image.
However, I want to make cells to have different pictures.
Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array of images instead of var myImage because collection view or tableview need some form of list or array to store all items. The indexPath.row will return the index of the images the collectionview is looking for. i.e.

`var images: [String] = ["image1", "image2"]`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image =  UIImage(named: self.images[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Also in function `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`
return `self.images.count`

Here is the complete code assuming you have a custom CollectionViewCell class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var images : [String] = ["image1", "image2"]
private let reuseIdentifier = "MyCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.image =  UIImage(named: self.images[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.images.count
    }

}
```

Comment: i get a error in        cell.imageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row]

Comment: it says cannot assign a value of type 'string' to a value of type "UIImage?"

Comment: you need this line cell.imageView.image =  UIImage(named: self.images[indexPath.row])

Comment: but that gives me array out of range when i run app

Comment: the array out of range usually happens when the numberOfItemsInSection doesn't match number of items in array. Could you show me your code, please?

Comment: No. that gives me other error;  2015-06-30 13:29:55.391 UI[886:133805] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Joonwoo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/276A5F76-29DF-4E8C-A86C-1F379B913652/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/41410096-CDF3-454A-8CAE-05D6B1FFD1F0/UI.app> (loaded)' with name 'ImageViewCellCollectionViewCell''
*** First throw call stack:
(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148259/continue-from-uicollectionview-please-answer      First one is CollectionViewCell.swift and second one is ViewController.swift Original, third one is ViewController.swift edited

Comment: I see your code now. So, you dont use the nib which mean you create the UI like UIImageView by code. So, from what I see compare to mind. Please change `self.collectionView.registerNib(nipName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)` with `self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")` . I will update my code to use the same class as you.

Comment: However, i'm still getting fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb)  at     cell.imageView.image =  UIImage(named: self.images[indexPath.row])

Comment: In func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellCount
    } return cellCount instead of self.images.count

Comment: No worries. Glad it's working now. If you want to know more about custom cell. Here is a link http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1 It might look complicated but give you an idea about nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your images coming from?

Suppose I have a 2D array of images like myImageArray[][], then change line:

```
cell.imageView.image = myImage
```

to

```
cell.imageView.image = myImageArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Comment: I certainly hope he doesn't have an array of images! That's a horribly wasteful use of memory. Hopefully, it's just arrays of image names.

Comment: This gives me only one image in every cells